# Add/Merge new Item in all json object in array that has same value in another different json object in array Vue Js

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, vue.js

Hi I am a newbie I am trying to Add/Merge new Item in all json object in array that has same value in another different json object in array Vue Js. I only know how to push another json object in json anyone can advice me I will really appreciate any advice or help. Thanks in advance

```
JSON 1 (Main)

[
  {
    name: "a",
    id: 2,
    price: 300
  },
  {
    name: "b",
    id: 3,
    price: 100
  },
  {
    name: "c",
    id: 4,
    price: 50
  }
]


JSON 2 (List)

[
  {
    color: "red",
    id: w2,
    uuid: "3"
  },
  {
    color: "blue",
    id: y2,
    uuid: "4"
  },
  {
    color: "pink",
    id: xf,
    uuid: "3"
  },
  {
    color: "black",
    id: jf,
    uuid: "7"
  }
]
```

if uuid  of JSON 2 (List) is same as id of JSON 1 (Main) add another item in JSON 2 (List) inside object named as name value will be  JSON 1 (Main) name  and remove json object of JSON 2 (List) that has uuid not match in id of jSON 1 (Main) like

```
  {
    color: "black",
    id: jf,
    uuid: "7"
  } //will be remove



    Expected Output
[
  {
    name: "b",
    color: "red",
    id: w2,
    uuid: "3"
  },
  {
    name: "c",
    color: "blue",
    id: y2,
    uuid: "4"
  },
  {
    name: "b",
    color: "pink",
    id: xf,
    uuid: "3"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to return a list of matching items. This is very powerful way of manipulating arrays, allowing you to return a wide variety of outputs.

We iterate through the json2 array, and we try to find a match in the json1 array (using [Array.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)). If we find a match based on uuid = id, we add the merged object to the array we return;

```js
let json1 = [ { name: "a", id: 2, price: 300 }, { name: "b", id: 3, price: 100 }, { name: "c", id: 4, price: 50 } ];

let json2 = [ { color: "red", id: 'w2', uuid: "3" }, { color: "blue", id: 'y2', uuid: "4" }, { color: "pink", id: 'xf', uuid: "3" }, { color: "black", id: 'jf', uuid: "7" } ];

let result = json2.reduce((returnArray, item) => {
    // Let's look for a match in the json1 array.
    let match = json1.find(el => el.id == item.uuid);
    if (match) {
        // If we find a match, create a merged object (using all of the json2 props and name from json1.
        returnArray.push({ ...item, name: match.name});
    }
    return returnArray;
}, []);

console.log("Result:", result);
```

Comment: Thank you very it is working fine and you explained it very nicely thank you  really appreciate  your help

Comment: No problem at all! Very glad to help! If you can learn .map, .filter and .reduce for arrays, these are very useful. Happy Coding!